# sinatra undefined method 'rewind'

Tags: android, ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to post some data from my Android app to Sinatra on my computer. Sinatra listens with:

```
post '/upload' do
    puts "*****************************************"
    puts "!!!!!!!! #{params.inspect}"
end
```

And fails with:

```
ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `rewind' for "ho":String
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/utils.rb:576:in`block in parse_multipart'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/utils.rb:499:in`loop'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/utils.rb:499:in`parse_multipart'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/request.rb:270:in `parse_multipart'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/request.rb:148:in `POST'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in `call'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1272:in `block in call'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1303:in `synchronize'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1272:in `call'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
        D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

The post params are `{"hey" => "ho"}`. I printed out the `body` variable inside rack/utils.rb and got `"ho"`, which I assume is why Sinatra chokes. I can't figure out why, though. Posting to a different server is successful. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I can post the java code but, as usual for java, it's extremely verbose. I also think it's not the problem as it does succeed in posting to a remote server, as I mentioned.

Comment: This question is answered in [another so question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933588/rescue-from-nomethoderror/7294036#7294036)

Comment: Yeah, I also had to modify the source in rack utils to get it to work. I like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584195/is-this-a-bug-in-rack/6783208#6783208 as a solution more, though, since it doesn't require messing around with the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
post '/upload' do
    puts "*****************************************"
    puts "!!!!!!!! #{params.inspect}"
end
```

Sinatra will always try to use the last returned value as the data to parse before sending it as http data.
Here your last instruction is `puts "!!!!!!!! #{params.inspect}"` which return `nil`.

```
post '/upload' do
    puts "*****************************************"
    puts "!!!!!!!! #{params.inspect}"
    "Information received"
end
```

Here Sinatra has some string to use and is happy

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to be it. I have the exact same error. Adding `httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` on the Android side seems to help Sinatra, but it's obviously not the right approach.